# AngularJS pass variable to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

I have this factory:

```
factory('getJson', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('json/greetings.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

the file is hardcoded, 'greetings.json', and I want the factory to get files according to the checkboxes in my view:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="includeVeggies" />Veggies</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="includeGreetings" />Greetings</li>
```

Any idea how do I go about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return a function:

```
.factory('getJson', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return function (file) {
        return $resource(file, {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
        });
    };
}]);
```

Then in your controller:

```
.controller('MyController', ['getJson', function (getJson) {
    getJson('json/greetings.json');
});
```

[Here's a Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lu724a5eoea3T5kyqLfm).

Comment: it returns undefined.

Comment: Also, in this way, how do I make a callback to assign the response only after the server has fetched the file?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: Got it!
I was missing getJson('json/greetings.json').query()